# Best way to recursively find all files (REST API)

Tags: ruby, recursion

I have two classes in my REST API wrapeer: `Wrapper::Folder` and `Wrapper::File`. Each folder can contain numerous folders and files. The contents of folder can be retrived by `.list.` class method.

I want to implement `.all` class method for `Wrapper::File` which would return an array of all files in all folders.

The following method doesn't work but shows something like I want.

```rb
class Wrapper::File
  def self.all
    folders = Wrapper::Folder.list('/')
    files = []
    while folders.size > 0
      folders.each do |object|
        if object.is_a?(Wrapper::Folder)
          folders = Wrapper::Folder.list('/')
        else
          files << object
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but this would be the basic gist of the recursive solution. Would return an array of file names (with paths) and without directories.

```
def getFilesRecursive(path)

   # create our directory object and file list storage
   d = Dir.new(path)
   l = Array.new

   # iterate over our given directory
   d.each do |f|

     # exclude . and ..
     if !(f =~ /$[\.]{1,2}^/)

       # recurse on a directory
       if File.directory?(f)
         l += getFilesRecursive(path + f)

       # store on a file
       else
         l.push(path + f)
       end

     end # if not . or ..

   end # Dir.each

   # return our list of files
   return l

end # getFlesRecursive()

# let's get some files!
files = getFilesRecursive("/")
```

Comment: It operates with directories and files through `Dir` and `File` while I can't do this. It wrapper for REST API and files differ from directories only with class name.

Comment: Solution will basically be the same - _self.all_ needs to accept a _path_ parameter and the first list call should be _folders = Wrapper::Folder.list(path)_. Remove the outer _while folders.size > 0_ and instead of _Dir.each_, use _folders.each_ (or even _Wrapper::Folder.list(path).each_). Directory test, needs something like _files += self.all(object)_ to recurse into the directory structure rather than repeating the same list call. Else condition looks ok. After your iterator, you'll need to return your files array (which will be recursively pushed back to _files += self.all(object)_ array.

Comment: Actually, instead of path, it looks like you could pass in a Wrapper::Folder object and get your list from there.